# Count rows of payroll week that relate to a payroll period

Tags: symfony, dql

I would like to count the number of rows that start date and end date of payroll week prepopulated matches the start date and end date of the payroll week entered.

What I have so far:

```
return $this->_em ->createQuery(' SELECT pw FROM comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollweek pw WHERE pw.startdate = :startdate AND pw.enddate <= :enddate ')
            ->setParameter('startdate', $startdate)
            ->setParameter('enddate', $enddate)
            ->getResult();
```

Comment: What I have so far return $this->_em
    ->createQuery('
    SELECT pw FROM comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollweek pw
    WHERE
       pw.startdate = :startdate
AND pw.enddate <= :enddate
')
->setParameter('startdate', $startdate)
->setParameter('enddate', $enddate)
->getResult();

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `COUNT` to your query and replace the equality to the first date by a greater or equal comparison.

Note that you can use [`BETWEEN`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#other-expressions) instead of this double comparison.

```
return $this->_em ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('COUNT(pw)')
            ->from('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollweek', 'pw')
            ->where('pw.startdate >= :startdate AND pw.enddate <= :enddate ')
            ->setParameter('startdate', $startdate)
            ->setParameter('enddate', $enddate)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();
```

Comment: What if its two results getOneorNullResult () would still work

Comment: The `COUNT`always return at most 1 result.

Comment: I get an error saying Error: Call to a member function setPayrollperiodid() on string @ this line in the controller  **$pWeek->setPayrollperiodid($entity);**

Comment: Here we're **retrieving** informations, while the error you've got is about **setting** information. Please make another question with this error as it's not related.

Comment: I have created the question with the error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45587282/error-call-to-a-member-function-setpayrollperiodid-on-string

Comment: I've checked your other question, and the answerer for it is right, if you want to get all the payrolls, you have to remove the `COUNT` and retrieve them with `getResult()`. But in this actual question, you've asked specifically **to count** the number of rows, in which case my answer is correct. With my answer, you've got the `countBystartdateAndenddate` function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151506/discussion-between-sue-and-veve).

Comment: Thanks Veve, this answered my question. :-)