# Error: Call to a member function setPayrollperiodid() on string

Tags: symfony

I'm having an error, when I try to create a record it gives me this error, Error: Call to a member function setPayrollperiodid() on string in C:\wamp64\www\AgripayrollsystemV2\AgriPayrollSystem\src\com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Controller\PayrollperiodController.php. This line: ** $pWeek->setPayrollperiodid($entity);**

**Entity**

```
    <?php

namespace com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity;


//use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


/**
 * Payrollperiod
 *

 */
class Payrollperiod
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *

     */
    private $payrollperiodid;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *

     * @Assert\DateTime()
     */

    private $startdate;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * 
     * @Assert\Type("DateTime")
     * message="The end date must be after the start date")
     */
    private $enddate;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *

     * 
     */
    private $state;

    public function getPayrollperiodid() {
        return $this->payrollperiodid;
    }

    public function getStartdate() {
        return $this->startdate;
    }

    public function getEnddate() {
        return $this->enddate;
    }

    public function getState() {
        return $this->state;
    }

    public function setPayrollperiodid($payrollperiodid) {
        $this->payrollperiodid = $payrollperiodid;
    }

    public function setStartdate(\DateTime $startdate) {
        $this->startdate = $startdate;
    }

    public function setEnddate(\DateTime $enddate) {
        $this->enddate = $enddate;
    }

    public function setState($state) {
        $this->state = $state;
    }

    /**
     * Render a payrollPeriodID as a string.
     * 
     * @return string
     */
     public function __toString()
    {
     return (string) $this->getPayrollperiodid();

    }



}
```

**Controller**

```
  public function createAction(Request $request)
    {

    $entity = new Payrollperiod();

    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

    $form->handleRequest($request);


        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) { 

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $payrollperiod = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollperiod')->findOneBy(['startdate'=>$form->get('startdate')->getData(), 'enddate'=>$form->get('enddate')->getData()]);

        $payrollweek = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollweek')->findBystartdateAndenddate($form->get('startdate')->getData(), $form->get('enddate')->getData());

        //If entity exists
        if ($payrollperiod){
                $this->addFlash('error', 'Payroll Period exist.');
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod'));
            }
            //If PayrollWeek matches the Payrollperiod entered
           elseif ($payrollweek){

            foreach($payrollweek as $pWeek) { 
            **$pWeek->setPayrollperiodid($entity);** 
            //$em->persist($pWeek);
            } 

          $em->persist($entity);
          $em->flush();

            $this->addFlash('error', 'Payroll Period was added.');
            $this->addFlash('error', 'Payroll week was updated.');
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod'));
           //return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod_show', array('payrollperiodid' => $entity->getpayrollperiodid())));
             }
             else{
               $this->addFlash('error', 'Payroll Period does not match a payroll week.');
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod'));  
             }
       }

       //return $this->render('comtwclagripayrollBundle::new.html.twig',array('form' => $form->createView()));
       return array(
           'entity' => $entity,
           'form'   => $form->createView(),
       );   

        }
```

**Custom Repository**

```
 return $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('payrollweek')
         ->select('COUNT(pw)')
         ->from ('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollweek','pw')
         ->where ('pw.startdate = :startdate and pw.enddate = :enddate')
        ->setParameter('startdate', $startdate)
        ->setParameter('enddate', $enddate)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneorNullResult();
}
```

Comment: Try to print the content of $payrollweek please

Comment: results: array (size=1) 1 => string '0' (length=1)

Comment: it was printing fine until I added this query  return $this
            ->createQueryBuilder('payrollweek')
             ->select('COUNT(pw)')
             ->from ('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollweek','pw')
             ->where ('pw.startdate = :startdate and pw.enddate = :enddate')
            ->setParameter('startdate', $startdate)
            ->setParameter('enddate', $enddate)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneorNullResult();
    } this query is to count the number of rows that matches r=the start and end date entered. Don't know if that's the problem

Comment: This is the error, you are trying to call setPayrollperiodid where pWeek is '0'. I don't know why but I suppose that inside your method findBystartdateAndenddate (if you have write It) there is something wrong, or inside the entity

Comment: so it shouldn't be a for loop then, how can I fix it

Comment: Do you have write this method findBystartdateAndenddate?

Comment: Yes I do. I will update the question with it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151475/discussion-between-sue-and-alessandro-minoccheri).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are returning a count not entity from your repository.

So you could change your repository into this if you wanna set your foreign key:

```
 return $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('pw')
         ->select('pw')
         ->from ('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollweek','pw')
         ->where ('pw.startdate = :startdate and pw.enddate = :enddate')
        ->setParameter('startdate', $startdate)
        ->setParameter('enddate', $enddate)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

And inside your controller try this:

```
 elseif (null != $payrollweek){
     foreach ($payrollweek as $entity) {
         $pWeek->setPayrollperiodid($entity); 
         $em->persist($pWeek);
     }
 }
```

If you wanna count  the row, use another function to do It

Inside your repository you could have something like this:

```
class PayrollweekRepository
{
    public function findBystartdateAndenddate($startdate, $enddate)
    {
       return $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('pw')
         ->select('pw')
         ->from ('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollweek','pw')
         ->where ('pw.startdate = :startdate and pw.enddate = :enddate')
        ->setParameter('startdate', $startdate)
        ->setParameter('enddate', $enddate)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
    }

    public function countBystartdateAndenddate($startdate, $enddate)
    {
        return $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('payrollweek')
         ->select('COUNT(pw)')
         ->from ('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollweek','pw')
         ->where ('pw.startdate = :startdate and pw.enddate = :enddate')
        ->setParameter('startdate', $startdate)
        ->setParameter('enddate', $enddate)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneorNullResult();
    }
}
```

Inside your controller you can call this:

```
$counter = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollweek')->countBystartdateAndenddate($form->get('startdate')->getData(), $form->get('enddate')->getData());
```

Comment: hey Alessandro this didn't produce what I want. But I want to know is it possible to have a while in repository/controller

Comment: Hey Alessandro is it possible to still help me out

Comment: You can have a while but I repeat that your problem isn't clear and my suggestion is to open a new question with the clear problem, this question for me is closed, try to open a new with the clear problem and I will help you :)

Comment: Hey Alessandro I have created a new question, can you help me out with it please

Comment: as soon as possible I'll try to answer

Comment: But first I advise to accept this answer to close this question well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45618502/using-count-in-doctrine-query-language

Comment: Alessandro do you have time to assist me now, I'm lost as to get what I want and really wants the help :(

Comment: Hi Alessandro I'm still waiting on the assistance as I don't know how else to accomplish the results i want. Please I'm asking for your help

Comment: Hey Alessandro, can you answer a question for me please.

Comment: I have tried to read your question but is very unclear for me the problem, sorry

Comment: this is not the question.

Comment: it is related to asp.net and iis. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45948663/authorization-roles-in-asp-net-and-iis

Comment: I don't know about asp.net and iis, :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153487/discussion-between-sue-and-alessandro-minoccheri).