# Authorization Roles in ASP.net and IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I'm new to using vs 2017 ASP.net and IIS, I'm able to access some of the pages but others I get the unauthorized error,

```
HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized You do not have permission to view this directory or page.
```

I have this in one the controllers [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, Issue, Transaction_Edit, Print")] but when I remove it I still get the same error.  `<authentication mode="None" />`Is there some authorization that I should change in IIS.
Even when I use [AllowAnonymous] I'm still being blocked. I'm also connected a database on a server, would that cause an error?

**IIS Authorization**

```
 Deny Anonymous Users
    Allow Administrator
    Allow All Users
```

**Web.config**

```
 <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
            <allow roles="Administrator" />
        </authorization>
```

Comment: You mention controllers, is this mvc? Perhaps there is another filter active. Check WebApiConfig.cs for something like: config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute()); Also try using the [AllowAnonymous] attribute.

Comment: yes it is and i have also tried using [AllowAnonymous] but i get the same error

Comment: What happens if you add _<authentication mode="None" />_ to _<system.web>_ in web.config?

Comment: <authentication mode="Windows">
    </authentication>

Comment: Please change it to _<authentication mode="None" />_ so you can test if that works.

Comment: i get this error HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized

You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153178/discussion-between-sue-and-ruard-van-elburg).

Comment: @Ruard van Elburg

Comment: Hi Ruard van Elburg, is there a possibility you could tell me what the other issues could be causing it to give that error.